# Does starting parenthesis in Bash case statement have meaning?

Tags: bash

I have found a case statement in a Bash script which looks like this:

```
case $i in
    (0) set -- ;;
    (1) set -- "$args0" ;;
    (2) set -- "$args0" "$args1" ;;
    (3) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" ;;
    (4) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" ;;
    (5) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" ;;
    (6) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" ;;
    (7) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" ;;
    (8) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" "$args7" ;;
    (9) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" "$args7" "$args8" ;;
esac
```

I've never seen the use of a starting `(`, I've only ever seen `SOME_CASE) command list ;;`. I can't find any reference to this other format - does this starting parenthesis have any special significance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The starting parenthesis is optional, but it (usually) leaves balanced parentheses which makes it easier in editors like `vim` which can jump from a close bracket (such as `)`, `]`, `}`) to the matching open bracket, accounting for nested brackets.  It has no other significance.

The original Bourne shell did not support the leading open parenthesis.

See also the POSIX shell specification for `case` under [Compound commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) or the Bash manual under [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs).

---

It also looks as if your script is crying out to use a Bash [array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) (see also [Shell Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters)).

```
declare -a args

args+=("argument 0")
args+=("argument 1")
args+=("argument 2" "argument 3" "argument 4 with spaces")

set -- "${args[@]}"
```

No `case`; no limit on the number of arguments.  How you build the array is open to discussion, but the one line instead of a 10-way `case` is compelling.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't find a reference for it, much appreciated.

Comment: Also, not my script, it belongs to someone else on the internet... :-) Nice tip on the array, thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

According to:

```sh
man 1 bash
```

the format of the `case` operator is:

> case word in [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list ;; ] ... esac

The opening bracket is in square brackets, which means it's not required.